# Tool to trace and create a script of all DB writes

Tags: database, sql-server, sql

We have a complex process that creates various entries into a large database.  I would like to generate a single SQL script that performs all the writes that are done by a single run of this process.  For example, if I run complex process it might do:

1. Insert ...
2. Insert ...
3. SELECT ...
4. Update ...
5. Insert ...

I want to extract 1 script that does:

1. Insert, Insert, Update, Insert

I don't care about the SELECT because that is a read.  Is there a tool that can do this?  Note that if the tool also creates the reads that is fine as they can simply be ignored.

Comment: For which DB engine/s?

Comment: Updated question to show ms-sql